# React parent access state from child

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactive-programming

How can I display state from child inside parent in React?

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
        <form>
            <h1>***CHILD STATE CHECKED***</h1>
            {this.props.children}
        </form>
        )
    }
})

var Checkbox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            checked: true
        }   
    },

    toggle: function() {
        this.setState({
            checked: !this.state.checked
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.toggle} aria-checked={this.state.checked} role="checkbox"></div>
        );
    }
})

ReactDOM.render(
    <Form>
        <Checkbox />
    </Form>,
    document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

What is the best way to display the state of the child inside its parent (especially inside this  tag in parent component)?
Is this possible without "ugly tricks"?
I want add some nodes or other components to the form when checkbox is checked.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly ? Displaying if the `<Checkbox/>` is checked where you wrote `***CHILD STATE CHECKED***`?

Comment: yes i want to display state from checkbox (state.checked) inside this text `** *CHILD STATE CHECKED***`

Comment: Do you want to only have one checkbox inside the form or it's for the sake of the example ?

Comment: I want to dynamically add a components inside Form component and then accesing some values (states for example) from this child components inside Parent

Comment: Ok, why do you want to do this ?

Comment: cuz i want add some nodes or other components to the form when checkbox is checked, maybe i want do it wrong?

Comment: If you want to react to a changing state of one of the child, you should pass down a callback as props to do it. Edit your question with this specific use case so I can help you by writing a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do not call toggle in Checkbox. Pass a callback from Form class to CheckBox class.

In Form Class:

```
return(
        <CheckBox onClick={this.onClick} />
)

    onClick(){
        console.log('Checkbox clicked');
    }
```

In CheckBox class:

```
    <div onClick={this.props.onClick} aria-checked={this.state.checked} role="checkbox">
```

Manage state in parent class, not in child class.

Answer (score 0):

Although if the answer to manage the state for this CheckBox in parent's state is correct, in some a bit more complicated cases you might still need to pass the state from child to component: concept is similar, you'll need [to pass a function from parent to child](https://kolosek.com/react-props-basic/), which will be used like a callback, and in which you will handle that child's state:

```
var Form = React.createClass({
    handleChildStateChange: function(newChildState) {
        // handle the child state change here
    }

    render: function() {
        const updatedChildren = React.Children.map(this.props.children,
            (child) => {
                return React.cloneElement(child, { updateParent: this.handleChildStateChange });
        });
        return (
            <form>
                <h1>***CHILD STATE CHECKED***</h1>
                {updatedChildren}
            </form>
        )
    }
})
```

Then, when updating the state in child component, call the passed function with new state as a parameter (I use [functional setState](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/functional-setstate-is-the-future-of-react-374f30401b6b) here because of asynchronous nature of state):

```
var Checkbox = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            checked: true
        }   
    },

    toggle: function() {
        this.setState((state) => {
            state.checked = !state.checked;
            this.props.updateParent(state);
            return state;
        });
    },

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div onClick={this.toggle} aria-checked={this.state.checked} role="checkbox"></div>
        );
    }
})
```

In the end, the render you used remains the same:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Form>
        <Checkbox />
    </Form>,
    document.querySelector('#app')
);
```

If you want to learn more about passing of props from children to parents, [this article](https://kolosek.com/react-props-communication) might be helpful.